# Find string between matching patterns

Tags: regex, powershell

In PowerShell I want to capture string between the first `:` and first `,` or first `//` (see examples below).

Example 1:

> Iteration: Hourly, Hours: 0, Minutes: 15Frequency: "Minutes/Hours: every 15 minutes"

Output:

> Hourly

Example 2:

> // Iteration: Once // Frequency: "Once: at 9:57 AM on Thursday, April 28, 2016"

Output:

> Once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$string = 'Iteration: Hourly, Hours: 0, Minutes: 15Frequency: "Minutes/Hours: every 15 minutes"'
$regex = ':\s*(.+?)(?=,|\/\/)'
[regex]::Match($string, $regex).Groups[1].Value
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fH4kK3/1)

Comment: Why did you put a pipe and double the slashes within the char class?

Comment: it will break on matching single `/`

Comment: anything in character class is treated as single character..So it won't be `//`

Comment: You are right - I changed my regex to use a postive lookahead

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in `powershell`

```
'// Iteration: Once // Frequency: "Once: at 9:57 AM on Thursday, April 28, 2016"' -match ':\s*(.*?)(?:,|\/\/)' | Out-Null; $Matches[1]
```